# Pure function as a variable of another function

Tags: function-construction, pure-function

In a notebook, I have a function that basically needs to do something like calling a pure function within a function. I would say that what best describes would be an example like:

```
f[x_, func_: # &] := func[x]
```

The problem with this is that when I use it, for example just `f[x]` the output is `f[x]` or `(#1)[x]` and if I call `f[x, (1 + #) &]` the output is `(1 + #1)[x]`

Even worse, if, for some reason, I decide to change the definition of `f` to

```
f[x_, func_: Exp] := func[x]
```

and then change it back to the original definition, the output to `f[x]` will now forever be `Exp[x]`.

So, is there a way to solve this problem so that with the first definition I get the result I'm waiting `f[x] = x` and `f[x, (1 + #) &] = 1 + x`?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `f[x_, func_: (# &)] := func[x]` otherwise it is (func_: #) &

Comment: Yeah, that seems to solve it! Thanks

Comment: From all the stuff that I tried to find a solution, never thought it would be as simple as that

Comment: @Argidore There exists a concept `Precedence` of operators. The problem arises from the fact that `Function (&)` has a rather low precedence. This can be seen by running this command: `Precedence /@ {Pattern, Optional, Function}`.

Comment: Arn't the two definitions `f[x_, func_: (# &)] := func[x]` and `F[x_, func_] := func[x]`  the same?

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann The result they give should be identical. The only actual difference is that `f[x_,func_:(#&)]` has a default value for `func`. So, you could call `f[x]` and it would give you `x` but `F[x]` just gives you an error.

Comment: @ Argidore very tricky, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

To specify values to a function's argument(s) which take effect when calling the function but no explicit values are going to be set to them, besides `Optional (:)`, one can also use `Default (.)`:

```
Default[f, 2] = #^2 &;

f[x_, func_.] := func[x]

f[a]
```

> ```
> a^2
> ```

In this case, no bother with precedences of operators.